# XmlTextReader ignores second and third Profile element

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xmltextreader

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!--This document contains the profiles that have been created.--><Profiles>
  <Profile>
    <name>One</name>
    <date>Two</date>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <name>One</name>
    <date>Two</date>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <name>One</name>
    <date>Two</date>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

The problem is that when I use XmlTextReader, it only reads the first profile and ignore the second and third.

```
    public ArrayList ReadProfiles() {

  ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
  Hashtable currentProfile = null;

  string currentName = "";
  string currentValue = "";  

  XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(profilesPath);
  // Read until end of file
        while (textReader.Read()) {
   switch(textReader.NodeType) {

   case XmlNodeType.Text: {
    currentValue = textReader.Value;
    Debug.Log("found text = " + currentValue);
    }
    break;

   case XmlNodeType.Element: {
    currentName = textReader.Name;
    switch(currentName) {

    case "Profiles": 
     Debug.Log("found profiles");
     break;
    case "Profile":
     Debug.Log("found profile");
     break;
    case "name":
     Debug.Log("found name");
     break;
    case "date":
     Debug.Log ("found date");
     break;
    default:
     Debug.Log("default in");
     break;
    }
   }
    break;
   case XmlNodeType.Comment:
    Debug.Log("found comment");
    break;
   case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
    Debug.Log("found end element" + textReader.Name.ToString());
    break;
   default:
    Debug.Log("default out");
    break;
   }
  }

  textReader.Close();

  return result;
 }
```

so I get:
[image]

Comment: I do not see the same behaviour as you are seeing. I copied the code, making one small change Debug.Log -> Console.WriteLine and I see that the profile is being read three times. Are you sure you are reading the file you think you are reading. Try a textReader.ReadOuterXml() at the top of your while statement to see exactly what is in the file you are reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output from my test with exactly same code and data.
Replace Debug.Log with Writeline.

```
default out
found comment
found profiles
default out
found profile
default out
found name
found text = One
found end elementname
default out
found date
found text = Two
found end elementdate
default out
found end elementProfile
default out
found profile
default out
found name
found text = One
found end elementname
default out
found date
found text = Two
found end elementdate
default out
found end elementProfile
default out
found profile
default out
found name
found text = One
found end elementname
default out
found date
found text = Two
found end elementdate
default out
found end elementProfile
default out
found end elementProfiles
default out
```

Comment: Thanks!, I found that Debug.Log() prints very slowly each result. I couldn't use Console.WriteLine() but instead I concatenated every result in the same string and at the end the parsing was complete.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid XML. Only one root node is permitted by the XML specification (processing instructions don't count as nodes) and your input stream contains multiple root nodes. If you put that through a validator it will barf.